# problem with konika-minolta magicolor 4750en

Tags: printing

I am teacher in 12k. In my classroom are 16 pc's and 1 konika-minolta magicolor 4750en network printer. In earlier versions of Ubuntu this printer works fine. But now it has no working. I can see printer from any computer on network. But when i send to it print job, then it just make some noise, but no printing. I try some other Linux distributions and discover, that only in Fedora it will work great. Not Arch, SuSE, all Ubuntu/Debian based distros
How can i solve this problem? I use original PPD files from manufacturer provided CD. I was try other PPD's, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing the device driver:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-m2300w
```

Then use the printer with the application `system-config-printer-gnome`

Comment: It did not help. Now printer print every job in 101 page. On every page are single line of unreadable unicode symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but maybe my solution can help someone else.  I am still using my Magicolor 4750DN and recently changed from Slackware to Ubuntu.  I had the same problem as described above, where the printer just spins but never prints anything.  In Ubuntu 18.04, I was using the latest (2011!) drivers (available on the KonicaMinolta website) and a standard IPP port in CUPS.

To fix the problem, I found I had to use the old PPD driver off the printer's installation CD (konica-minolta-magicolor-4750.ppd) and use the AppSocket/HP JetDirect with the URI socket://[printer_ip_address] and port 9100.  This finally worked for me.